# Js : multidimensional-array error in nested while half of this still working

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

Can anyone explain why the 4th sub-array isn't working anymore? I believe because `input[(i + 1)]` is `undefined`? But it works for another... 
I'm a newbie and still learning how to figure out the best option.

```
function dataHandling(){


    for (var i=0;i < input.length   ; i++){
    for(var j=0; j < input[i].length; j++)
     /*
      if(j === 0){
         console.log("Nomor ID: "+ input[i][j] );
      }
      else if(j=== 1){
        console.log("Name: "+ input[i][j] );
      }
      else if(j=== 2){
        console.log("Birthplace n date: "+ input[i][j] +" " + input[i+1][j+1]);
      }
      else if(j=== 4){
        console.log("Hobby: "+ input[i][j] +"\n" );
      }
      */
     switch(j){
        case 0:
          console.log("Nomor ID: "+ input[i][j] );
          break;

          case 1:
          console.log("Name: "+ input[i][j] );
          break;

          case 2:
          console.log("Birthplace and date: "+ input[i][j] +" " + input[i+1][j+1]);
          break;

          case 3:
         // console.log("birthdate: "+ input[i][j] );
          break;

          case 4:
          console.log("Hobby: "+ input[i][j] +"\n" );
          break;

           default:
        break;
      }


    }

}

 var input = [
                ["0001", "Roman Alamsyah", "Bandar Lampung", "21/05/1989", "Reading"],
                ["0002", "Dika Sembiring", "Medan", "10/10/1992", "Playing Guitar"],
                ["0003", "Winona", "Ambon", "25/12/1965", "Cooking"],
                ["0004", "Bintang Senjaya", "Martapura", "6/4/1970", "Codding"]
              ];

dataHandling(input);
```

While it works for 1st-3rd arrays, it always errors in the 4th:

```
Nomor ID: 0003
Name: Winona
Birthplace n date: Ambon 6/4/1970
Hobby: Cooking

Nomor ID: 0004
Name: Bintang Senjaya
TypeError: input[(i + 1)] is undefined <<<
```

I can understand if since the first `i` will error but only the 4th of `i` which not able to read the next sub-array. (Sorry for explaining with a newbie's way, still hard to explain with limited knowledge.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd just like to say that you're doing great so far with learning Javascript. The error is you're trying to access the fifth array when `i=4` and you use `input[i+1][j+1]`. Luckily, that isn't even a problem; what you want to do is access the same sub-array, but the next item, so only `j` should be increased by 1 (`input[i][j+1]`):

```js
function dataHandling(){


    for (var i=0;i < input.length   ; i++){
    for(var j=0; j < input[i].length; j++)
     /*
      if(j === 0){
         console.log("Nomor ID: "+ input[i][j] );
      }
      else if(j=== 1){
        console.log("Name: "+ input[i][j] );
      }
      else if(j=== 2){
        console.log("Birthplace n date: "+ input[i][j] +" " + input[i+1][j+1]);
      }
      else if(j=== 4){
        console.log("Hobby: "+ input[i][j] +"\n" );
      }
      */
     switch(j){
        case 0:
          console.log("Nomor ID: "+ input[i][j] );
          break;

          case 1:
          console.log("Name: "+ input[i][j] );
          break;

          case 2:
          console.log("Birthplace and date: "+ input[i][j] +" " + input[i][j+1]);
          break;

          case 3:
         // console.log("birthdate: "+ input[i][j] );
          break;

          case 4:
          console.log("Hobby: "+ input[i][j] +"\n" );
          break;

           default:
        break;
      }


    }

}

 var input = [
                ["0001", "Roman Alamsyah", "Bandar Lampung", "21/05/1989", "Reading"],
                ["0002", "Dika Sembiring", "Medan", "10/10/1992", "Playing Guitar"],
                ["0003", "Winona", "Ambon", "25/12/1965", "Cooking"],
                ["0004", "Bintang Senjaya", "Martapura", "6/4/1970", "Codding"]
              ];

dataHandling(input);
```